# configuring LOAD function in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

Input file in HDFS => /user/xyz/abc/part-m-00000

file content :-

100002030,Tom,peter,eng,block 3, lane 5,california,10021

100003031,Tom,john,doc,block 2, lane 2,california,10021

100004032,Tom,jim,eng,block 1, lane 1,california,10021

100005033,Tom,trek,doc,block 2, lane 2,california,10021

100006034,Tom,peter,eng,block 6, lane 6,california,10021

Schema File -

rollno,firstname,lastname,qualification,address1,address2,city,Zipcode

IS it possible to do a load as follow:-

Input = Load '/user/xyz/abc/part-m-00000' using PigStorage(',');

SF=load 'user/xyz/abc/sf.txt';

X= Load 'Input' using PigStorage(',') as (SF);

It doesnt work
Please note that I donot want to hardcode the field names

Appreciate quick help, thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

PigStorage has a second constructor which takes multiple options and one of them is -schema.
Based on documentation, create a hidden file .pig_schema which contains your schema and it will load your schema from this while loading the data.
More details are here 
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.html

Here are steps:
First thing you need to do is create schema manually

```
// Load data by specifying schema
A = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray, amount:float);
// Now store data in with -schema option to create schema
STORE A INTO 'output' USING PigStorage(',', '-schema');
// above statement will create .pig_schema file in "output" directory. copy this file to your source directory 'data'
Now load data without specifying Schema

A_WITHOUT_SCHEMA = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage(',');

// view the schema of relation by issuing describe statement.
DESCRIBE A_WITHOUT_SCHEMA;

// The output should be something like 
{name: chararray, amount: float}
```

I hope that clarifies the solution.

Comment: can you please elaborate with an example